# How to install custom SQL with Django

Tags: python, sql, django

What's the best way to deploy custom SQL for views used by unmanaged Django models?

I have a model myapp.models.MyModel using a view myview.sql, specified in the models "db_table" meta attribute. So, following [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/#database-backend-specific-sql-data), I placed the custom SQL file in myapp/sql/myview.sql.

However, after I run `python manage.py syncdb`, the view is not installed. Running sqlcustom similarly does not show the view.

What else do I need to do so Django will automatically detect and deploy my custom SQL?

Answer (score 8):

`python manage.py sqlcustom` will only output the custom SQL statements that you've defined, but you need to execute them in the database. Of course, you can copy and paste, but if you want to automate the process and have it be less tedious/error-prone, one easy way to do so (at least on a *nix environment) is to use a pipe:

`python manage.py sqlcustom myapp | python manage.py dbshell`

Comment: In hindsight, this doesn't seem to work reliably. `sqlcustom` outputs nothing for an unmanaged model using a SQL view for a specific db backend. e.g. myapp/sql/mymodel.sql shows up, but myapp/sql/mymodel.postgresql.sql does not.

Comment: Note that sqlcustom is going away in Django 1.9, with the recommendation to use RunSQL instead.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/#providing-initial-sql-data), name the file myapp/sql/mymodel.sql instead of myapp/sql/myview.sql

Comment: That does make my sql display when I run sqlcustom, but syncdb still does not install it.

Comment: @Cerin Have you dropped the DB table before redo syncdb? As you can see in the output of sqlcustom, customized sqls are bundle w/ create table sqls in single BEGIN...COMMIT block. You could run syncdb with -v 3 to check what it does for you

Comment: The app in question is managed by South, so I guess Django ignores custom sql in South apps...and unfortunately South does not support migrating custom SQL...